# Adding a list of events in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm not sure how to do this in angular, after coming from jquery.

I have a table:

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="val in data">
  <tr>
    <td>val.Time</td>
    <td>val.Distance</td>
    <td ng-click="callmethod()"><img src="delete"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Essentially I want the callmethod() to know which row is being clicked so that I can make a update in the model in my controller. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: just pass the object as argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change that ng-click to this:

```
<td ng-click="callmethod(val)"><img src="delete"></td>
```

You'll get the whole val object when that method gets called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $index property:

```
callmethod($index)
```

Then on your controller you would do something like:

```
function callmethod(index) {
   var foo = $scope.data[index];
}
```